# android widget run a function by press a button in the widget

Tags: android, widget

I want to add a button in my widget so that it can run a function(change APN and display a changed message in the widget) by press a button. In fact, the function is worked since I have tested in an activity. Did anyone have idea how to do it? thanks!

Regards,
Bill Chan

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is couple of ways.

For example you can make something like this inside registered AppWidgetProvider:

```
public static String ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER = "Action!";

@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent active = new Intent(context, ThisClass.class);
        active.setAction(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER);

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                0, active, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, actionPendingIntent);


        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteViews);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_DELETED.equals(action)) {
            final int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            if (appWidgetId != AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
                this.onDeleted(context, new int[] { appWidgetId });
            }
        } else {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) {
                doYourStuff();
            super.onReceive(context, intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In addition, how to update the widget content (i.e. change the text in widget)  in doYourStuff()? Thanks